# How to read file line by line using "For loop" in c++?

Tags: c++

I have coding experience in C# but I am beginner in c++.

How to read file line by line using below "for loop".

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
}
```

I found this piece of code but I couldn't understand.

```
for (string line = ""; getline(infile, line); )
    {
        //do something with the line
    }
```

Comment: `getline(infile, line)` reads a line at a time. When used as the "test" condition (either in a `while` or `for` loop) you loop reading lines until the stream-state is no longer good (usual change due to end-of-file). So the loop, simply uses `getline()` as the test condition and reads a line each time the test clause is checked.

Answer (score 2):

As you know the `for` loop runs until the middle part returns `false`, which is:

```
getline(infile, line)
```

`getline` in this case returns false if there's nothing more to read so this will loop every line of the file assuming `infile` is the opened file as an fstream.

Answer (score 2):

The standard streams in C++ can be used in conditions to check if they have an error or have reached the end of the file.

And the [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function returns (a reference to) the stream passed as the first argument.

This can be combined, so the `std::getline` call can be used in a condition, as shown in the second piece of code in your question.